# Error in const bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);

Tags: javascript, database

```
function readImageFile(file) {
const bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
const buf = new Buffer.from(bitmap);
return buf;
}
dir.files(__dirname, function(err, files) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(files);
//we have an array of files now, so now we'll iterate that array
files.forEach(function(filepath) {
photo = readImageFile(filepath);


var query = 'UPDATE cloth SET access = "?" WHERE Image = "?"'
if (filepath.substring(35,filepath.length -4)!="x.js"){
values = [
photo,
filepath.substring(35,filepath.length -4)

];
pool.query(query, values, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log("BLOB data inserted!");
```

const bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'readFileSync')

I need to duplicate this function, how do I do it? I have several tables to load the BLOB into
I tried changing the ts values, but all in vain. I'm zero in JavaScript and I need to submit a paper. Please help me.

Comment: `const fs = require("fs")`?

Comment: Is this being run in node.js?  Is this the entire file?

Comment: Your edit doesn't address any of the issues raised by the comments.

Comment: "I'm zero in JavaScript and I need to submit a paper. Please help me." — [That isn't relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because the **fs** module, which contains the **readFileSync** function, is not being imported or defined in your code.

To fix this, you need to import the **fs** module at the top of your code by adding this line:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

To duplicate the function, you can simply copy and paste the entire **readImageFile** function and give it a different name. However, keep in mind that if you are going to use the new function in a different file, you will need to import the fs module in that file as well.